# Efficient way to find unique value in one of few lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have right now such code with 2 lists:

```
movies = [{'name': '007: Spectre', 'year': 2015, 'length': '2:05'}, 
          {'name': 'Terminator Genesis', 'year': 2015, 'length': '2:20'}]
rest_movies = [{'name':'Bridge of Spies', 'year': 2015, 'length': '1:50'},
               {'name': 'Star Wars', 'year': 2015, 'length': '2:30'}]

check_if_movie_in_one_of_lists = 'Star Wars'

for line in movies:
    name = line['name']
    if name == check_if_movie_in_one_of_lists:
        movie_year = line['year']
            print(movie_year)
        break
else:
    for line in rest_movies:
        name = line['name']
        if name == check_if_movie_in_one_of_lists:
            movie_year = line['year']
            print(movie_year)
            break
```

I think this is not pythonic way to check if there is needed value in one of the lists.

In my case:

1. Lists can have random size.
2. Amount of lists also can be random (right now just 2, but will be more).
3. No duplicate values among lists.
4. Looking for solution for Python 3

Comment: I've read your question several times, and I have no idea what you're trying to do. Your title doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code samples, and those do wildly different things - can you clarify?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, edited :) Hope right now my question is easier to understand)

Comment: It would seem you would be **way** better off just storing the movies in dictionaries of the form `{'movie': year}`, e.g. `{'007: Spectre': 2015, 'Terminator Genesis': 2015, ...}`.

Comment: @wflynny, inside of each dict can be lots of info, for example 'length' (as I just added to show as additional option), 'director', 'actors', etc.

Comment: @TitanFighter Are you reading in json or parsing html or something?  If so, there are standard libs to make this lookup faster.

Comment: @wflynny parsing html. Movies and showtimes from cinemas. Lets say Im parsing once a day. 1st day I'm parsing info and pickle it. On 2nd day Im unpickling '1st day info' and store it in 'movies', then check if the same htmls have any new info (added new movies) by comparing unpickled info with just parsed. If there is difference (there are new movies), then info of the 2nd day (just new movies, wo old) I append to 'rest_movies'. But new movies can be seen in many cinemas and in order to avoid parsing the same movie's page in order to get year (again), i want to get it already from parsed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

So if you must keep things in the current structure, the best way would just be:

```
movie_lists = [movies, rest_movies, ...]
for movie_list in movie_lists:
    for item in movie_list:
        if item['name'] == movie_to_find:
            print(item['year'])
            break
```

But this only makes sense if you are using this information once.  If you  need to do this multiple times (O(n)*m), it makes sense to loop through once to construct the dicts of the form `name: year`, then utilize the speed of dict lookups (O(n) + O(1) << O(n)*m).

---

I would change your two lists to two dicts because dict lookups are O(1) (where list lookups are O(n)):

```
movies = {'007: Spectre': 2015}, {'Terminator Genesis': 2015}
rest_movies = {'Bridge of Spies': 2015}, {'Star Wars': 2015}

movie_to_find = 'Star Wars'

if movie_to_find in movies:
    print(movies[movie_to_find])
elif movie_to_find in rest_movies:
    print(rest_movies[movie_to_find])
```

For a general solution with multiple dicts, store the dicts in a list and iterate through the list:

```
movie_sets = [movies, rest_movies, other_movies, ...]

for movie_set in movie_sets:
    if movie_to_find in movie_set:
        print(movie_set[movie_to_find])
```

To convert you list of dicts to standalone dicts:

```
movies = dict((m['name'], m['year']) for m in movies)
rest_movies = dict((m['name'], m['year']) for m in rest_movies)
```

Comment: in many tries just found out the same solution :) P.S. By the way, additional thank you for this information: (O(n) + O(1) << O(n)*m). This is my next step of code optimization.

Answer (score 0):

To find a value in a list use `list.index(value)`. This will give you the index of the specified value in the list.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

Example:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> lst.index(1)
0
>>> lst.index(3)
2
```